# How to configure laravel-mix to be able to use @material with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix, vue-loader, material-components-web

I need some help with configuring material-web-components to work with vue.js components. The error occurs when I want to import a @material component scss into my vue component.

SomeVueComponent.js:

```
<style lang="scss">
    @import '@material/textfield/mdc-text-field.scss';
</style>
```

The error is that some @material components import other @material component scss, but cannot be found because of the includePaths, which I fixed by adding this code into my laravel-mix file:

webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
   module: {
       rules: [
           {
               test: /\.vue$/,
               loader: 'vue-loader',
               options: {
                   loaders: {
                       scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?' + JSON.stringify({
                           includePaths: ['node_modules']
                       })
                   }
               }
           }
       ]
   }
});
```

After saving this file everything compiles correctly but now I get this error for all of my vue components on the site:

[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

After a whole day of researching on how to fix this, I found out that the conflict is generating because I push the vue-loader 2 times with webpack (The default one + my custom one).

Does anyone know a workaround on how to do this? It would be really helpful.

I am using:

- laravel 5.7.8
- laravel-mix 4.0.15
- vue 2.6.10
- vue-loader 15.4.2
- webpack 4.27.1

I have already tried the new way to import vue components after vue-loader v13+. (Adding the .default after the require) Still same vue error.

```
Vue.component('some-vue-component', require('./components/SomeVueComponent.vue').default);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SomeVueComponent.js:

<style src="@material/textfield/mdc-text-field.scss" lang="scss"></style>
```

Comment: Hi, that doesn't solve the problem, it just imports the '@material/textfield' component scss, that component relies on other components inside '@material', which don't get imported because it looks for '@material' from inside the root instead of the 'node_modules' folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel 6**

webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css', {
    sassOptions: {
        includePaths:  ['./node_modules']
    }
});
```